# no limited session time,refreshing automaticly session wth out load page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-2

How to refreshing session in ASP.NET MVC 2 with out reload age?
I use this line but not good work,becose reload page

```
meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300"
```

Comment: Session has nothing to do with page refresh.

Comment: In this line do with page refres?how to solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are afraid that your session will expire after a certain amount of inactivity from the user (no requests), you could activate sliding expiration for the session in web.config and then put a bit of javascript which will send AJAX requests to some dummy action to the server at regular intervals to maintain the session alive.

For example if you are using jQuery:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("keepsession")',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false
    });
}, 300000);
```

Comment: We used this with success where we had internal users (with authority) that essentially demanded no timeouts so they could leave the browser open as long as they wanted without issues.

Comment: thanks
"keepsession" example function/methode?

Comment: `public ActionResult KeepSession() { return Content(Session.SessionID); }`.